# Transactions not rolling back all changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6.  I have created a class and coded it so when it is instantiated it creates a database context named _ctx.  The class has an Execute() method that looks like this:

```
using (var txn = _ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        _ctx.Messages.Add(new Message()
            {
                MessageId = messageId,
                ReceivingApplication = receivingApp
            });

        var message = _ctx.Messages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.MessageId == 178);  // This message ID is INVALID
        message.IsValid = hl7Data.IsValid;

        _ctx.SaveChanges();
        txn.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        txn.Rollback();
    }
}
```

There is no message with an ID of 178, so an exception is thrown which is then caught and the txn.Rollback() line is executed.  What confuses me is that the new message was inserted into the database.  I would have expected this to be rolled back since it was within the scope of the transaction.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try using `TransactionScope` instead.

Comment: I tried as you suggested and got the same results.  As soon as I try to set message.IsValid an exception is thrown and scope.Complete() is never called yet the new message row is still added to the database.

Comment: Where do you call SaveChanges() so data update goes to the db? You don't call it in the code you've posted.

Comment: Yeah, it's in the code above...just above the call to txn.Commit().  But the exception is thrown before that call is made, so that makes it even more strange.

Comment: Well, nevermind...I appreciate your help because it got me down the right track with the SaveChanges() question.  My issue was in the calling code, not this code.  Thank you!